# issues with lucee server installed on nginx

Tags: nginx, server, coldfusion, lucee

we had setup an nginx server where we are trying to manage the site
This is the directory path that the lucee server is using: `/opt/lucee/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/pathtofulfill.com/`

the webiste is opening like: `www.pathtofulfill.com/pathtofullfill.com/ndex.cfm - want to browse the site like this:`www.pathtofulfill.com/ndex.cfm` - what change should i do and where

our nginx is just doing this:

```
location / {
      proxy_pass  http://localhost:8888/;
}
```

trying like this:

open the server.xml file in the folder as;  /lucee/tomcat/server.xml
and add this code

```
<Host name="https://www.pathtofulfill.com" appBase="ROOT">
       <Context path="" docBase="E:\lucee\tomcat\webapps\ROOT\pathtofulfill.com\" />
   </Host>
```

before the `</Engine>` closing and restart lucee server after that

and will that it takes care of the certificate

Comment: I don't have any experience with NGINX. Also I'm not sure, whether you're using Windows or other OS ( Linux / Mac ). But what i can see here is the path(s).

If /opt/lucee/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/pathtofulfill.com/ is the application root, the you should give the same path in server.xml ( as docBase ). Does that help any way?

Comment: Also please take a look at here https://dev.lucee.org/t/configuring-nginx-with-mod-cfm/1401

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to make sure you have a site set up in NGINX to direct traffic to the root of your folder.  A proper lucee installation should setup the NGINX connector configuration for you.  You just need to put some site configs in for NGINX to read off of.

Maybe something like this...

```
server {
   listen 80 default_server;
   server_name pathtofulfill.com www.pathtofulfill.com;

   root /var/www/pathtofulfill.com/;

   gzip on;
   gzip_min_length  1100;
   gzip_buffers  4 32k;
   gzip_types    text/plain application/x-javascript text/xml text/css;
   gzip_vary on;

   set $lucee_context "pathtofulfill.com";
   include lucee.conf;
}
```

You'll also want to make sure your tomcat server.xml file is configured properly.

Example :

```
<Host name="pathtofulfill.com" appBase="webapps">
    <Context path="" docBase="/var/www/pathtofulfill"/>
    <Alias>pathtofulfill.com</Alias>
    <Alias>www.pathtofulfill.com</Alias>
</Host>
```

That should be about it off the top of my head.  Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You may also care to check your lucee_proxy.conf file and ensure that your mod_cfm shared key matches your tomcat server.xml shared key.